# Flexbox Navigation Bar with Menu Items on Both Sides and Centered Logo

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a navigation bar built using flexbox and would like 3 sections. Links on the left, links on the right, and the logo in the center. However, if I try to use flexbox for this, my logo ends up offset if the content of the links on the left are different from those on the right. So how do I center my logo?

[image]

This is the HTML:

```
<nav>
<div class="logo">
    <img src="img/logo.svg"/>
</div>
<ul>
    <li><a href="/about.html" class="selected">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="/about.html">Work</a></li>
    <li><a href="/about.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

This is the CSS:

```
nav {
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
}

nav > .logo {
    flex-grow: 1;
}

nav > .logo > img {
    height: 1rem;
}

nav > ul {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

nav > ul > li {
    margin: 0 1rem;
}
```

Comment: See boxes #71-78 in the duplicate post.

Comment: Great, guess I wasn't searching for the right stuff. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  margin: 0; padding: 0; }

nav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo img {
  width: 200px; }

nav > ul {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

nav > ul > li {
    margin: 0 1rem;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
      <li><a href="/about.html" class="selected">Home</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="logo">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg/2000px-Google_2015_logo.svg.png"/>
  </div>
  <ul>
      <li><a href="/about.html" class="selected">Home</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

You don't need to use flex-grow: 1 in logo. You can specify width for logo and use justify-content: space-between; and align-items: center;

`align-items: center` make your elements vertically align while `justify-content: space-between` separate your elements equally on free space .